# How to change a password

Tags: updates

How do I change my password in ubuntu?  I think I have either 12.4 or 12.10.  I'm a bit computer illiterate, so will need an answer for a computer dummy.

Answer (score 1):

You've two ways to change the password.

1. **Using GUI -** Go to **System** -> **Preferences** -> **About Me**, which will display the following window. Click on **Change Password** button.
2. **Command -** Open up a terminal (you can do that by holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) & type as below;

> passwd username

This will prompt you to type your new UNIX password by confirming once.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You don't need to specify the username, `passwd` works for the current user by default.